# jplayer just stopped working in Chrome - OK in other browsers

Tags: google-chrome, jplayer

I've been using jplayer jukebox for some time with no problems but it has suddenly stopped working in Chrome.  Still works fine in IE and Firefox but the playlist no longer shows in Chrome.  It was definitely working at the end of June 2014 when I last added a track. webpage is http://www.jonphilibert.com/gallery.htm

Any suggestions gratefully received
Hilary

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "mp3" to "M4A".

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jplayer/Lyk7Znv1pWE

Answer (score 0):

What has happened is that [this Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=386073) means that Chrome uses Flash for playback since Chrome 36, rather than HTML5.

Your problem is that the path to the SWF path is set up incorrectly - Chrome Console tells me "GET http://www.jonphilibert.com/Jplayer.swf 404 (Not Found)"

So once you configure the player to have the correct SWF file path, playback should start working again in Chrome.

Note this means that playback also won't be working in other browsers that don't support HTML5 audio.